# how to print text present in the <p></p> tag in selenium using ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a code like `<p id="playlist-name"> today's hit song</p>` in my project. I used

```
driver.find_element(:id, 'playlist-name').text
```

but it returns "nil" as a output as instead of 'today's hit song'.
Please help..

Comment: Your one should work, can you try - `driver.find_element(:css, 'p#playlist-name').text` ?

Comment: I tried with driver.find_element(:css, 'p#playlist-name').text but still i am getting nil as output.